# Queryable.Aggregate is not working with null values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable, linq-expressions

I'm writing a visitor which transforms `IQueryable` query. It uses `Aggregate` method with seed `null` and then use some func to transform it. My problem is that this null is of type `decimal?`. But I get an exception

```
'Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter of type 
'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]' of method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal] 
Aggregate[Nullable`1,Nullable`1]
(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]], 
System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal], 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],
System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]])''
```

After some research I found that it's `Aggregate` itself which is ruining my query:

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Expression<Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate>> func) {
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (func == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("func");
    return source.Provider.Execute<TAccumulate>(
        Expression.Call(
            null,
            GetMethodInfo(Queryable.Aggregate, source, seed, func),
            new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Constant(seed), Expression.Quote(func) }
            ));
}
```

My problem is with `Expression.Constant(seed)` which is `null` and `Expression.Constant` transforms it into constant of type object:

```
public static ConstantExpression Constant(object value) {
    return ConstantExpression.Make(value, value == null ? typeof(object) : value.GetType());
}
```

Thus my `new decimal?()` transforms into `(object) null` and I get this error.

Is there any workaround for this? It seems to be impossible to get fix in .net framework (and even if it's possible, it will be fixed in 4.7 or later). I'l create a pull request for this however I'm sure it won't be accepted.

Code snippet to reproduce:

```
var result = new int?[] {1}.AsQueryable().Aggregate(default(int?), (a, b) => b);
```

Comment: Using custom Aggregate is not an option in your case?

Comment: I guess you could modify your visitor to emit direct call with correct `Expression.Constant` instead of using `Queryable.Aggregate`.

Comment: @user1892538 try to add some logic into labmda. You will encounter multiple casts, which are kinda slow on large collections. And this is anyway is silly way to do such things.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using now `Enumerable.Aggregate` instead, which is working fine, but still looking for something better.

Comment: @user1892538 I agree that it solves this problem. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: @user1892538 however, solution with `Enumerable.Aggregate` looks cleaner. I can post gist here which is solving this if you want so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the code snippet to reproduce

```
var result = new int?[] {1}.AsQueryable().Aggregate(default(int?), (a, b) => b);
```

I'd change it into

```
var result2 = new int?[] {1}.AsQueryable().DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate((a, b) => b);
```

If you want a sum equivalent

with empty collection

```
var result3 = new int?[0].AsQueryable().DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate(
   (a, b) => a.GetValueOrDefault() + b.GetValueOrDefault());
```

containing null

```
var result4 = new int?[]{1,2,null}.AsQueryable().DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate(
 (a, b) => a.GetValueOrDefault() + b.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Basically, I'm suggesting to use `DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Expression<Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate>> func) {
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (func == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("func");
    return source.Provider.Execute<TAccumulate>(
        Expression.Call(
            null,
            GetMethodInfo(Queryable.Aggregate, source, seed, func),
            new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Constant(seed, typeof(TAccumulate)), Expression.Quote(func) }
            ));
}
```

Comment: Obviously, this is simply how the fixed version of the BCL method should look like - but you can't just fix it in MS sources.

Comment: @user1892538 I want equivalent of `Sum` method which returns `null` if collection is empty or all elements are `null`.

Comment: Probably if you want help with yours code you should provide yours code, but not one from system assembly. Also you can name this routine AggregateEx and use it successfully instead of system Aggregate. But it looks like yours explanation of what you are trying to do and yours actual problem is not complete.